# Rank model with QAIC using MuMIn

Tags: r, logistic-regression, information-theory, mumin

I need to rank candidate model using the QAIC criterion. This is what I've tried:

```
library(MuMIn)
model_global <-  glm(vs ~ mpg + disp + wt, family = quasibinomial, mtcars)
model_1 <-  glm(vs ~ mpg, family = quasibinomial, mtcars)
model_2 <-  glm(vs ~ disp, family = quasibinomial, mtcars)
model_3 <-  glm(vs ~ wt, family = quasibinomial, mtcars)
model_null <-  glm(vs ~ 1, family = quasibinomial, mtcars)

mod.sel(model_global, model_1, model_2, model_3, model_null, rank="QAIC", chat=deviance(model_global) / df.residual(model_global))
```

This returns this error:

```
Error in formula.default(x) : invalid formula
```

How can I rank the above models using QAIC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide your `rank.args` as a `list` (see `?model.sel`)

```
library(MuMIn)
model.sel(model_global, model_1, model_2, model_3, model_null,
          rank = QAIC,
          rank.args = list(chat = deviance(model_global) / df.residual(model_global)))
```

In the (nice little) example you provided, `chat` happens to be `< 1`, a warning is generated, and `chat` is set to 1.

```
# Model selection table 
#              (Intrc)  disp    mpg    wt     df logLik  QAIC delta weight
# model_global -21.9000 -0.0403 0.6470  5.332 4   -8.844 25.7  0.00 0.569 
# model_2        4.1380 -0.0216               2  -11.348 26.7  1.01 0.344 
# model_1       -8.8330         0.4304        2  -12.767 29.5  3.85 0.083 
# model_3        5.7150                -1.911 2  -15.683 35.4  9.68 0.004 
# model_null    -0.2513                       1  -21.930 45.9 20.17 0.000 
# Warning messages:
#   1: In rank(x, chat = 0.631714762477434) :
#   'chat' given is < 1, increased to 1
# ..snip..
```

Comment: Henrik: what version of `MuMIn` are you using? I'm using 1.9.13. When I are run your code, the only variables I get in the model selection table are `(Intrc)` `disp` `mpg` `wt` `df`. I do not get the other 4.

Comment: @luciano, I use 1.9.13. I am glad you are asking, because at one point I actually got the 'partial' output you describe, for no obvious reason. I can't say if I did something particular to make it work again - it 'suddenly' did. Perhaps `MuMin` is a bit shaky, or clashes with other loaded packages. You may try the old classic: restart R, and run the script in a fresh session.

Comment: Exactly same happened to me. Initially I got partial output then after several tries I suddenly got full output. Maybe a bug?

Comment: I am actually very surprised that you get log-likelihood with quasi* family that does not provide one (as I explained in my answer earlier and `?QAIC`). So the output that @luciano got is not a bug, but expected behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

It's really all in the manual, so please read it first (`?model.sel` and `?QAIC`). Note two issues in your code:

- arguments to `QAIC` in `model.sel` are passed in the `rank.args` argument, not directly.
- models of *quasi-* families do not report a likelihood, needed to calculate QAIC. See *Note* in `?QAIC` and `example(QAIC)` for a hack to go around this.